# Programmatically prolonging the duration of Android loading indicator on the splash screen

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Is there anyway via code to prolong the duration of the Android loading indicator on the splash screen?

In the Player Settings, I choose the large one and I also include:

```
#if UNITY_ANDROID
    Handheld.SetActivityIndicatorStyle(AndroidActivityIndicatorStyle.Large);
#endif
```

But no matter which one is done, the loader only appears for a fraction of a second which is not noticeable to the user.

Our android app has a long loading time, so I would like a way of telling the user that something is happening...

I don't think there is anyway to place something on this splash screen (like a UI element with a message, etc...) for user feedback. Is there??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can** prolong the Splash screen with Unity's [`SplashScreen`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.SplashScreen.html) API. Initialize splash screen with `SplashScreen.Begin()` then wait in a `while` loop while calling `SplashScreen.Draw();` to draw the splash screen every frame. You must also yield or wait in that `while` loop so that your whole game will not freeze.

```
bool keepShowingSplashScreen = false;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    SplashScreen.Begin();

    while (keepShowingSplashScreen)
    {
        SplashScreen.Draw();
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

When you want to exit the splash screen, set `keepShowingSplashScreen`  to `false`. The `while` loop will end and your game will continue.

Comment: You are welcome. I wanted to answer this question when it was asked but then forgot about it after my computer restarted. I remembered about it yesterday and decided to search for it again and answer it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to increase the time of android splash screen.
If your app have long loading time then you have to design your own loading screen using Progress indicator.

Comment: Thank you. By "Progress indicator" you are referring to a general indicator that people make with different UI stuff, or you are referring to something that is built-in in Unity?